# Return a list of free(unbound) variables in SML

Tags: types, sml, abstract-data-type, free-variable

I've created my own datatypes:

```
datatype typ = Bool | Int | Arrow of typ*typ;
(* i.e., Arrow(argType, returnType) *)
(* diMLazy expressions *)
datatype expr = TrueExpr
              | FalseExpr
              | IntExpr of int
              | VarExpr of string
              | PlusExpr of expr*expr
              | LessExpr of expr*expr
              | IfExpr of expr*expr*expr
              | ApplyExpr of expr*expr
              | FunExpr of string*string*typ*typ*expr
```

Using these, i need to write a function isFV that returns a list of any free variables passed into the function.
So far, my code is:

```
fun isFV (exp:expr) =
    let
      val bound_list = [];
    (*Contains returns true if x:string is within a string list.*)
      fun contains (i:string, str_list:string list) =
          foldr(fn (x,y) => i = x orelse y) false str_list;

      fun anaExp (ex:expr, aggr_list:string list) =
          case ex of 
              TrueExpr => []
            | FalseExpr => []
            | IntExpr (a) => []
            | PlusExpr (a, b) => anaExp(a,aggr_list) @ anaExp(b,aggr_list)
            | LessExpr (a, b) => anaExp(a,aggr_list) @ anaExp(b,aggr_list)
            | IfExpr (a, b, c) => anaExp(a,aggr_list) @ anaExp(b,aggr_list) @ anaExp(c,aggr_List)
            | ApplyExpr (a,b) => anaExp(a,aggr_list) @ anaExp(b,aggr_list)
            | FunExpr (a, b, c, d, e) => ??????
            | VarExpr (a) = if(contains (a,aggr_List)) then [] else [a]
    in
      anaExp(exp, bound_list)
    end
```

anaExp is meant to initially take an empty list and recursively call itself until it gets a VarExpr term. It'll then add that to aggr_list.

How do i apply the FuncExpr? I know to use the VarExpr as a string type, but what do i use as a typ type? Currently i have:

```
|   FunExpr (a, b, c, d, e) => anaExp(VarExpr(a),aggr_list) @ anaExp(VarExpr(b),aggr_list) 
                                    @ anaExp(c,aggr_list) @ anaExp(d,aggr_list) @ anaExp(e,aggr_list)
```

But we know that passing a typ into anaExp will cause a type error (c and d).

Comment: Immediate errors in your code: You want `VarExpr (a) = if ...` to be `VarExpr a => if ...`. The reason `aggr_List` is unbound is because the variable's name is written with a lowercase L but is consistently referred to with an uppercase L. Also, you didn't actually write a question.

Comment: Thank you that was a stupid mistake.

Comment: I've edited the post to include a question

Comment: What is a `FuncExpr`? Does it serve to *bind* some of the variables in the expression in its 5th parameter? I am trying to understand what it means for a variable  to be *free*. It would help if you provide a nontrivial example of an `expr` value, together with intended output of `isFV`

Answer (score 3):

> [...] a function isFV that returns a list of any free variables passed into the function.

Here is some feedback:

- That sounds like a bad name for a function that returns a list. It sounds like a good name for a predicate function that determines whether something *is* a free variable. Also, *the function* seems a bit unclear. I assume it is any expression fed to `isFV`.
- I assume that `FunExpr` is a lambda. For example, the expression *(λx.x+y) 5* is encoded as `ApplyExpr (FunExpr ("x", ?, Int, Int, PlusExpr (VarExpr "x", VarExpr "y")), IntExpr 5)`.

  I'm not sure what the second string parameter in `FunExpr` is used for. Maybe it's either a named *or* an anonymous function? That should probably make one of the parameters a *string option*...

  If `FunExpr` is a lambda, should *x* be considered a free or a bound variable in the expression *(λx.x+y) x*? Clearly, *x* is both at different times, but what should the function return?
- You have a fine basic strategy: a recursive function that traverses expressions and keeps an "aggregated list" of variables that have been seen in sub-expressions. If an expression is seen again, it is not included the second time.

  But if a variable occurs in separate sub-expressions, they are all included,
  e.g. `PlusExpr (VarExpr "a", VarExpr "a")` would produce `["a"] @ ["a"]`, because the aggregated list is not updated between calls to sub-expressions.
- You don't seem to differentiate between free and bound variables. Assuming that a `FunExpr` actually creates a bound variable, the aggregated state of your recursive function must be a little more complex to catch the distinction:

  A variable is not just free because it's a variable, but because it hasn't occurred as a bound variable in the current scope (maintained by some set of currently bound variables).
- It might be easier with a set type rather than the list type. Depending on your SML compiler, there might be a built-in set type. In SML/NJ, for example, you have a list-based set functor:

  ```
  structure Set = ListSetFn(struct
                              type ord_key = string
                              val compare = String.compare
                            end)
  ```

Here is a template for one solution:

```
fun getVars expr0 =
  let
    fun gv bound free expr =
        case expr of
            TrueExpr => (bound, free)
          | FalseExpr => (bound, free)
          | IntExpr => (bound, free)
          | VarExpr var => if Set.member (var, bound)
                           then ...
                           else ...
          | PlusExpr (a, b) =>
            let val (bound', free') = gv bound free a
                val (bound'', free'') = gv ... ... b
            in (..., ...) end
          | LessExpr (a, b) => ...
          | IfExpr (a, b, c) => ...
          | ApplyExpr (a, b) => ...
          | FunExpr (var, whatIsThis, _, _, a) =>
            let val bound' = Set.add (bound, var)
                val (bound'', free'') = gv ... ... a
            in (..., ...) end

    val (bound, free) = gv Set.empty Set.empty expr0
  in
    ...
  end
```

In this, think of

- when to update the bound and free sets, and
- if/when to use the returned bound and free sets.

> How do i apply the FuncExpr?

I don't understand that question. If you mean how you write the `FunExpr` clause in your function, you have to specify what it's trying to achieve to get any sensible feedback. So far, there has been a bit of guesswork on my side as to what these constructors are supposed to do.

> what do i use as a typ type?

As Ionuț said, the type does not matter for the output of this function.

Answer (score 1):

The `FunExpr` case is supposed to augment `aggr_list` with the name of the parameter that the function takes. I presume the first `string` of `FunExpr` is the function name and the second `string` is the parameter name. You should then add this parameter name to the list of bound variables, i.e., `aggr_list`, and then recurse on the function's body. You can safely ignore the function's types for this problem.